# How to use self-compose with sort-step to sort

Tags: sorting, scheme, racket

```
(define (compose f1 f2)
  (lambda (p2) (f1 (f2 p2))))

(define (self-compose f n)
  (if (= n 1) (compose f f)
      (compose f (self-compose f (- n 1)))))

(define (sort-step l f)
  (cond ((eq? l '()) '())
        ((eq? (cdr l) '()) (list (car l)))
        ((f (car l) (cadr l)) (cons (car l) (sort-step (cdr l) f)))
        (else (cons (cadr l) (sort-step (cons (car l) (cddr l)) f)))))
```

How to use self-compose with sort-step to sort?
Tried:

```
(define (sort-f l f)
  (self-compose (sort-step l f) (length l)))
```

test:

```
(sort-f '(8 4 6 5 3) >)  ===> arity mismatch;
the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 1
  given: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(sort-step l f)` is not a function of one argument as `compose` expects, it's a list.

Since you probably want to "thread" the list through the composition, you need to compose a function that takes a list and returns a list.

You can get one by rearranging `sort-step` slightly into a curried function:

```
(define (sort-step f)
  (lambda (l)
    (cond ((null? l) '())
          ((null? (cdr l)) l)
          ((f (car l) (cadr l)) (cons (car l) ((sort-step f) (cdr l))))
          (else (cons (cadr l) ((sort-step f) (cons (car l) (cddr l))))))))
```

Now `(sort-step f)` is a function from list to list and you can say

```
(define (sort-f l f)
  ((self-compose (sort-step f) (length l)) l))
```

Comment: how can i test:
(sort-step '(3 8 4 6 5) >)

Comment: would modifying self-compose to take more arguments be possible?

Answer (score 0):

The l param can also be thread by a lambda in the self-compose without rewriting sort-step:

```
(define (sort-f l f) 
  ((self-compose (lambda (l) (sort-step l f)) (length l)) l))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.